# git log errors with "... unexpected EOF ..."

Tags: git

I am using git version 2.11.0.windows.3 on Windows 10.  I can checkout, switch branches, commit, etc., but if I try something like git log I get:

```
'less: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
'less: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is this a configuration issue?  What steps should I take to resolve it?

Thanks and regards...Paul

Comment: "something" and "like", can you show the exact command that produces that error message?

Comment: Can you do the following, open up a command prompt, then execute `ECHO %PATH%` and see what the end of the output is?

Comment: git diff, git log and git show all produce the same errors as above.

Comment: ...;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;;C:\Python36;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Python36;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\

Comment: I think git is trying to use less for paging and I don't have it installed.

Just tried the command:

    git --no-pager diff

and that works.

Comment: `less` should come with git, perhaps your installation is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lasse.

You were quite correct, `less.exe` was in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` but unfortunately that directory wasn't on my search path.  I added the directory to my search path and all now works fine.

Best regards...Paul

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try and unzip [PortableGit-2.14.1-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.14.1-64-bit.7z.exe) in (for instance) `C:\git2.14.1`.

Then, in a CMD shell session (not bash), type:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\git2.14.1
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

In that session, your PATH will only reference Windows and Git 2.14.1.

Try again a Git clone, and your Git commands (like `git log`), to see if the issue persists.

If it does, as the OP comment, then Windows networking is at fault.

Comment: Hi VonC,  I'd rather use this route as a last resort as I'll probably end up spending hours trying to find out why I can't get PortableGit working properly.

Comment: @PaulOfford `less.exe` was in the path I suggested in my answer!